# try writing a program that asks the user for a phrase, and the number of exclamation marks(!) they would like to have following that phrase

Tags: python, for-loop

Has to be Python and a for loop
This is what i have:

```
str('input phrase')

variable = int(input("exclamation marks"))

for int in range(int):

    str += "!"
    
print(str)
```

Comment: You already ask for an input in the code. Just do it again (before the other input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the input to your variable `str` (although that's a bad naming convention) for your code to work.

```
my_str = input('input phrase: ')
variable = int(input("exclamation marks: "))
for i in range(variable):
    my_str += "!"
print(my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a loop in this situation.

```
answ =(input('input phrase ') + '!' * 
int(input('exclamation marks ')))

print(answ)
```